# Laravel route not calling function in controller

Tags: laravel

When I view `www.domain.com/blog`, it shows blank white screen and the function isn't being called in production but works locally.

### Route

```
Route::get('/blog', 'homeController@blog');
```

### Controller

```
public function blog() 
{
    //echo "Hii";exit;
    $seo_info = seoInfo();
    $allBlogs = DB::table('blogs')->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();
    return view('blog', compact('allBlogs', 'seo_info'));
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Is that `homeController` or `HomeController` ?

Comment: it is homeController.

Comment: In local or in server ?

Comment: In server.locally working fine.

Comment: have you tested other routes ? Basically it's due to permission issues or might be due to configuration caches.

Comment: Put your controller name HomeController and change your class name also it should work

Comment: Other routes working fine.Which file need to permission.

Comment: @MD.JubairMizan it is not working.all routes working fine except this.